# How to ignore the elements that are not occurring second time in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

If you look at the code below, you will see that it is going to find the number of occurrences of the elements from one vector `ar`. This means that it is finding the vector location of the same number when it is appearing again (only considered if that occurred for a second time).

Since I'm interested in to find the element in the vector `time`, with the associated first and second appearance vector position of elements in vector `ar`, I have done this below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double time1;
  double time2;
  vector<int> ar{ 1, 8, 6, 6, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8 };
    vector<int> time{ 100, 800, 600, 600, 502, 405, 700, 700, 700, 711, 118 };

  map<int, vector<size_t> > occurrences;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ar.size(); ++i) {
    auto iter = occurrences.find(ar[i]);
    if (iter == occurrences.end()) {
      occurrences[ar[i]].push_back(i);
    }
    else { //print the distance between the current and the previous occurrence
      cout << "distance with first occurrence of number "  << ar[i] << " is " << (i - iter->second[0])<< "\n";

    //time1= ar2[iter->second[0]];
    time2 = time[i];

    }

    //cout << "first occurance time" <<time1<<endl;
    cout << "second occurance element"<<ar[i]<<"the second occurance time is"<<time2<<"endl"<<endl;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

The only problem in the above code is that it is finding the vector elements from `time`, even though the elements in the same position in the vector `ar` were not repeated. What it means that I only want to consider printing out the vector element `time`, when I get any repeated elements from vector `ar`. And hence, I will print out the same vector position of `ar`, from vector `time`.

For example, the first element `1` in the vector `ar` was not repeated, therefore, I want to ignore the elements `100`from the vector `time`. Also, `ar[7]` element is 7, which was appeared in the vector more than the second time, so I also don't want to print the same vector position from `time`  too.

OUTPUT: [image]

From the output, I marked by red color, which I want to be ignored. The reason is that they are printed out elements (1, 8 etc) from vector `ar` did not appear again. I also want to ignore the vector position, when they appear more than twice.

Comment: Instead of trying to explain with words, give some example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code. For one, you print `second occurance element...` for *every* element of `ar`. For another, you never check to see whether an element appears more than twice. I advise you to work on simpler exercises before you attempt this one.

Comment: Yes, I checked only the second occurrence elements. The position of the second occurrence and the elements is correct, which I have checked.  The problem is that I wanted to print out the second occurrence position associated elements from the vector` time`.

Comment: @super I added the output and expected result in more detail.

Comment: your task is still unclear. As "second time" you mean second time repeatedly or not? 
If your vectors are related why just don't use vector of pairs?

Comment: @Reinstate Monica, Do you mean pair position of the two vectors, since I always print from the same vector position []? 

The second time means when the same element reappears in the vector `ar`.   For example,  ar[6] = first appearance of the number 7
ar[7] = second appearance of the number 7. 
I want to ignore if ar[7] = the third appearance of the number 7, or no reappearance at all.